# Нейронная сеть с несколькими слоями выхода на Python

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Нужно написать нейронную сеть на Python для `multi-label classification` без использования сторонних модулей для создания нейронных сетей. Прошу любой пример, сам в интернете ничего не нашел. Спасибо.

Comment: можете пояснить что значит `"с несколькими слоями выхода"`?

Comment: чтобы на выходе могло быть несколько значений. Такое возможно? Извиняюсь, если вопрос задан неверно.

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/creating-a-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-multi-class-classification/

Comment: вроде, подходит, спасибо.